# SSO between Spring MVC REST and Webshpere portal

Tags: spring, rest, security, spring-mvc, websphere-portal

I have a Spring MVC rest application that needs to be deployed in IBM WebSphere Portal v8.5, a script portlet will be used and interact with the deployed rest API, my question is related to security 
concerns, how can I make these rest API secured where only logged in users to the portal can see and access them. is there any SSO technique that can be achieved between the portal and the Spring MVC rest application, i do not want to use Spring security since it has a different security context.

Comment: What do you mean by a different security context ? And which security context you app is using ?

Comment: I mean if i use Spring Security, i will not be able to achieve SSO between the Portal and the deployed rest application i deployed, I need to allow all portal user to use the secured rest API as long as they are logged into the Portal

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring MVC rest application will reside on IBM WebSphere Portal which itself has the set security and also the permission for group of users to access the portlet. Now, this Spring MVC calling another services at the back-end, it will be done by the users who already have the permissions and secured per portal application.

I hope it is helpful and as per your conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your response;

Comment: Thanks for your response; Well, I have a java script application that resides on a Script portlet on IBM webSphere portal, from JavaScript i need to access the rest services provided by the Spring Rest MVC application, those rest services need to be secured. If i understand you well,  all i need is to set the declarative security i need (Basic or login form) at the web.xml of my spring rest application, hence only if the portal user is logged in, the script app will be able to call the REST API

Comment: Apologies for late response. 
Now to understand your question, may I know where does the Spring Rest MVC application reside? 
A portlet which is deployed on Portal will be secured if security is configured on Portal means keeping SSO/LTPA/SSL/Basic/Login Form certifications and the permissions given to users to access that portlet will only be able to access it and will be able to call Spring Rest MVC.

Hope it is clear and helpful.